# Is it possible to pull data like pictures or video which is being streamed or viewed over the internet from RAM?

Tags: assembly, memory-management

Please correct me if I am absolutely on the wrong track with this, but I am under the impression that when something is viewed over the internet it needs to be temporarily stored in RAM. And, one could then determine what addresses in RAM changed and access the data to display it elsewhere such as in another window. What sort of code would be required to do this or is their a better way of achieving the same end?

Answer (score 2):

If you really only want the image-data I would probably rather grab the screen-memory than trying to figure out where a webbrowser, videoplayer, etc... stores it's downloaded data.

DirectX on Windows is capable of reading the data back, from the whole screen across all applications (for a reference, see GetFrontBufferData() in the DirectX sdk) . Also most Platforms have a zooming-application that manages to achieve that somehow. I don't know about other platforms, but i guess that OpenGl on MacOS and X are also capable of that.

Answer (score 1):

in theory you are right - in reality your best bet (highest success rate) would be to write a kernel-mode driver and even then there would be cases you wouldn't be able to achieve the result you are looking for...
And even if you achieve what you are after depending on the specific case it could be illegal to do so...

WHY are you asking ?

Comment: Thanks for the help. I am looking into learning lower level languages like assembler and directX and was curious about how you could access data through it. This was intended as more of a theoretical question than something I want to specifically apply (certainly not if its illegal).